# Auto-renewable subscriptions calling SubscriptionsUpdated

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have implemented som auto renewable subscriptions in my app and everything works well. I perform a purchase in the app, everything gets synced to a server, and the server then checks the iTunes API as soon as the subscription has expired to detect if the subscription has been renewed.

One thing confuses me though. Every once in a while I get a call to transactionsUpdated within my app with a transaction with status: Purchased. This is usually done after I restart the app.

Why do I get these calls? Has it something to do with the subscription beeing renewed? Can I safely ignore these calls? Everything seems to work fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what Apple is doing is sending you a receipt for an automatic renewal of the subscription.  Because all durations are drastically shortened in the sandbox, the subscription will get automatically renewed by Apple every few minutes, for a limited number of times (like 5), before they stop renewing.

Since you're already checking for new receipts at the right time on your server, you can ignore the receipts they're automatically sending to the app on occasion.